# Title field is hidden in "New Item" form

Tags: content-type, newform, hidden

When I click "New Item", all of my other columns show up. However, my title field (it doesn't matter if it's 'Title', 'Title linked to item', or 'Title linked to item with edit') doesn't show up.

I've looked around and found the " Make sure 'Allow Management of Content' is switched to yes and make sure Title is not "hidden"" however, this did not solve my problem. "Allow Management of Content" is yes and under 'Content Type', Title is shown as "Required".

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have all other fields (which are getting displayed) in 'item' content type only?

Comment: Yes, I have. I don't know where is the problem.

Comment: Just for sake of testing issue, Can you save list as template and create a new list based on that template, and verify if the problem is same with new list as well?

Comment: If I try to create new list from this tepmlate i get a list, but when I open it, it writes that List does not exist.
I created this list when i migrate list from 2007 to SPS 2013 through MS Access

Comment: Problem might seems to be from list migrated. 1) To confirm it is not with environment try a new custom list with 1-2 fields, and verify its default form.If it works fine. then issue is certainly with migration.   2)Also you can do is create a new custom New form from SharePoint designer, for original list and verify if it is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [SharePoint Client Browser](https://web.archive.org/web/20180102133041/http://spcb.codeplex.com:80/) so see what settings this field has. You can not change settings with this tool.

[image]
<sub>(source: [codeplex.com](https://www.codeplex.com/Download?ProjectName=spcb&DownloadId=1393554))</sub>

Comment: Also the problem is when I create any new column, it doesn't appear in new form.

Comment: Check all ContentTypes on the List and make sure the correct one is default

Answer (score 0):

Use PowerShell and see if the field is set to hidden. You could then un-hide it if required:

```
$web = get-spweb http://sharepoint
$list = $web.lists.TryGetList["ListName"]
if ($list) {
    $fld = $list.fields | ? {$_.InternalName -eq "Title"}
    if ($fld) {
        $fld.ShowInNewForm
    }
}
```

To un-hide just update `$fld.ShowInNewForm` to

```
$fld.ShowInNewForm = $true
$fld.Update()
```